# Returning custom jsp if my custom validation fails during the spring security login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring 2.5 in my application
My application uses Spring Security for login. It has a class which implements the UserDetailService and overrides the loadUserByUsernamemethod.

In my loadUserByUsername I am doing an IP validation and if it is not successful I want to redirect user to a custom JSP page iperror.jsp.
How can I do that?
I tried throwing the exception in case of IP validation and catching the error in web.xml like:

```
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.salebuild.model.IPNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errors/ip_activation_required.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

But id doesent work.
Could anyone suggest how I can return a custom JSP on my custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can try throwing an AccessDeniedException and set your accessDeniedHandler with errorPage property with your error jsp